# Segoe MDL2 Assets + Regular font on one button

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to add Segoe MDL2 Assets with regular text in the same button in WPF Xaml. Working on a side menu that I want to have icons + text buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly set the `Button.Content` property:

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <Viewbox x:Key="ErrorIcon"
             x:Shared="False">
      <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}, Path=Foreground}"
                 FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                 FontSize="11"
                 Text="&#xE783;" />
    </Viewbox>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Button>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ContentControl Content="{Staticresource ErroIcon}"
                      Foreground="Red" />
      <TextBlock Text="Some button text" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Botton>
</Window>
```

You can override the `ControlTemplate` of the `Button` or extend `Button` if you want to implement it with reusability in mind.